# How to Import facebook contact using php and curl

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I want to create a contact importer application.How to Import facebook contact using php and curl(prefer screenscraping).Please anybody can help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a basic script to login in Facebook. You can check it out here:

http://pythonphp.blogspot.com/2010/08/login-in-facebook-with-curl-and-php.html

Comment: The blog seems to be removed now. Where else i can get the script?

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenInvitor:

http://openinviter.com/

It uses PHP/cURL to get not only Facebook but a whole lot of other languages too. Frequently updated and open source.